# Is there a Java API that creates BPMN?

Tags: java, api, business-process-management, bpmn

Is there a way to programmatically create [BPMN 2.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Process_Model_and_Notation) via a Java API?

I'm aware that I can use a graphical [modeling tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Business_Process_Modeling_Notation_tools) or create the [BPMN XML](http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/2.0/) by hand but I'm looking for a way to create it dynamically at run-time.

In my case, the BPMN will be executed through jBPM.  The [jBPM docs](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v5.2/userguide/ch05.html#d0e783) say you can use their API to define processes but they don't recommend its use "to shield yourself from internal APIs".  It would be great if there were an API that wasn't tied to a specific vendor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[EasyBPMN](http://research.petalslink.org/display/easybpmn/EasyBPMN+Overview) is one option. There is no "vendor neutral" way in that Java doesn't have a standard API for the concept (unlike, say generic XML manipulation), but this would be an option which would be more portable between workflow engines and modeling tools.

Answer (score 1):

the whole idea about the BPMN2 spec is to be vendor neutral, inside jBPM5 you have the fluent API that in some way allow you to create BPMN2 models that you can export. I'm not sure if it's up-to-date with the latest features that are supported in the XML but I'm pretty sure that you can create your own processes with it.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

BPMN2 model is based on EMF model (org.eclipse.bpmn2 project, model folder, BPMN20.ecore file). You can use EMF Java Api to create, read or modify BPMN2 models.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library from [activiti](http://www.activiti.org).
here there's a  [blog post](http://stacktrace.be/blog/2013/03/dynamic-process-creation-and-deployment-in-100-lines/) of one of the people behind activiti.
I did a [compiler that modifies a process](https://github.com/esseti/BPMN4Crowd-Compiler) based on this and it works.