# Which EMF classes are required to create a BPM2 file?

Tags: eclipse, jbpm, emf

The last response at this URL:

[Is there a Java API that creates BPMN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216207/is-there-a-java-api-that-creates-bpmn)

directs the user asking the question to use the EMF API, this appears like a good solution to my problem.  Do you know which classes in the EMF API would be involved in creating a bpm2 file?

Thank you in advance, any sample code, hints or direction is greatly appreciated.

-Wes

Comment: have a look at the sirius gallery https://eclipse.org/sirius/gallery.html there is already a bpmn designer from obeo.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to find/create BPMN Ecore model and generate model java files using EMF.